# Inner join is breaking SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a query:

```
SELECT systemuser.fullname AS 'fullname',
   usersettings.calendartype AS 'calendartype', 
   usersettings.uilanguageid AS 'uilanguageid' 
FROM   filteredsystemuser AS systemuser 
   INNER JOIN filteredusersettings AS usersettings 
           ON systemuser.systemuserid = usersettings.systemuserid 
inner join vfinduserguid vfg
on systemuser.systemuserid = vfg.userguid
```

which I have converted to FetchXML:

```
<fetch mapping="logical">
  <entity name="systemuser">
    <attribute name="fullname" alias="fullname" />
    <link-entity name="usersettings" to="systemuserid" from="systemuserid" alias="usersettings" link-type="inner">
      <attribute name="calendartype" alias="calendartype" />
      <attribute name="uilanguageid" alias="uilanguageid" />
      <link-entity name="vfinduserguid" to="systemuserid" from="userguid" alias="vfg" link-type="inner" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

using this service: http://www.sql2fetchxml.com/

When I try to use this FEtchXML within SSRS, I'm getting:

[image]

The specific record type does not exist in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Please note that it is the last join (vfinduserguid) that is breaking it. This object is a view.

Comment: Try to add `AS`,it seems to me is the only thing which is different,maybe it doesnt know implicit aliasing.

Comment: thank you, that will not change the fetchxml

Comment: The query Designer expects a T-SQL query not the XML you are entering. Simply enter the query you have written and it would bring back the result. You have the option to render reports in XML but not enter XML to query SQL Server database.

Comment: my data source accepts only fetchxml

Comment: I think probably CRM doesn't recognize your custom view vfinduserguid.  A fetch query works differently from a SQL query in that it is transformed into a SQL query by CRM before running and cannot just be run against any table or view in the database like a SQL query.

Comment: i see! in this case, could you suggest a more crm-friendly way of running a function from fetchxml within ssrs?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what the vfinduserguid view contains?

Comment: yes! here's what it contains http://pastebin.com/CkWjzefx

Comment: Are you trying to limit the result set of your query based on whether the user has a role of CRMReaderRole or db_owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fetch to get the current user:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform"
       mapping="logical" distinct="false">
   <entity name="systemuser">
      <attribute name="fullname" />
      <attribute name="systemuserid" />
      <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
      <filter type="and">
         <condition attribute="systemuserid"
                    operator="eq-userid" />
      </filter>
   </entity>
</fetch>
```

http://crmtipoftheday.com/2014/01/09/reflecting-current-user-ssrs/

Comment: thanks so much. very kind of you.  looks like CRM won't allow the user to check the role. getting the same error.

Comment: zach, i'm actually trying to just get the name of the user running the report